# Python: Differentiating between row and column vectors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

Is there a good way of differentiating between row and column vectors in numpy? If I was to give one a vector, say:

```py
from numpy import *
v = array([1,2,3])
```

they wouldn't be able to say weather I mean a row or a column vector. Moreover:

```py
>>> array([1,2,3]) == array([1,2,3]).transpose()
array([ True,  True,  True])
```

Which compares the vectors element-wise.

I realize that most of the functions on vectors from the mentioned modules don't need the differentiation. For example `outer(a,b)` or `a.dot(b)` but I'd like to differentiate for my own convenience.

Comment: The behavior that you are observing is actually *correct* "in the real world": a *one* dimensional sequence of numbers is neither a row nor a column vector. A row or column vector is in fact a *two* dimensional array (in which one of the two dimensions is 1). Thus, your tests should be done with `array([[1, 2, 3]])`, instead, which is not equal to its transpose.

Comment: This is actually mathematically not quite right. Matrices are mxn, and row vectors are by definition those where m=1, and column vectors are those where n=1. Dimensionality is different altogether in math, has to do with number of vectors in basis set in a vector space, so realy we shouldn't be talking about dimensionality of a single vector at all. I think that the original poster in talking about the "real world" was talking about the world of linear algebra and mathematics, so was correct. Programmers tend to use the terms wrong.

Comment: @neuronet, this is actually mathematically not *quite* right. What you are describing is the way things are e.g. in Matlab, and it is an extremely useful convention. The mathematically correct way would be to distinguish between vectors from a given space (per convention represented as columns) and vectors from its [dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) (per convention represented as rows).

Comment: Numpy really has a very poor representation of rows, columns and even the z axis vectors. Extremely unintuitive and annoying to use. I hope somebody creates a more intuitive wrapper over numpy.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can make the distinction explicit by adding another dimension to the array.

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a.transpose()
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a.dot(a.transpose())
14
```

Now force it to be a column vector:

```
>>> a.shape = (3,1)
>>> a
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
>>> a.transpose()
array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> a.dot(a.transpose())
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Another option is to use np.newaxis when you want to make the distinction:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a[:, np.newaxis]
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
>>> a[np.newaxis, :]
array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: I thought about that, but it means that __getitem__ becomes inconsistent: `a[0] = [1]`, `a[0][0] = 1` for column vector and `a[0] = 1`, `a[0][0] = TypeError` for row vector.

Comment: Yes, that's a trade-off you have to consider. Another option is to use np.newaxis when you need to make the distinction (see edit to my answer).

Comment: Another way of converting a row vector (1d array) to column vector (returns copy): `a.reshape(a.size, 1)`, or even `a.reshape(-1, 1)` if u r lazy like me

Answer (score 52):

Use double `[]` when writing your vectors.

Then, if you want a row vector:

```
row_vector = array([[1, 2, 3]])    # shape (1, 3)
```

Or if you want a column vector:

```
col_vector = array([[1, 2, 3]]).T  # shape (3, 1)
```

Answer (score 21):

The vector you are creating is **neither row nor column**. It actually has 1 dimension only. You can verify that by

- checking the number of dimensions `myvector.ndim` which is `1`
- checking the `myvector.shape`, which is `(3,)` (a tuple with one element only). For a row vector is should be `(1, 3)`, and for a column `(3, 1)`

Two ways to handle this

- create an *actual* row or column vector
- `reshape` your current one

You can explicitly create a row or column

```
row = np.array([    # one row with 3 elements
   [1, 2, 3]
]
column = np.array([  # 3 rows, with 1 element each
    [1],
    [2],
    [3]
])
```

or, with a shortcut

```
row = np.r_['r', [1,2,3]]     # shape: (1, 3)
column = np.r_['c', [1,2,3]]  # shape: (3,1)
```

Alternatively, you can reshape it to `(1, n)` for row, or `(n, 1)` for column

```
row = my_vector.reshape(1, -1)
column = my_vector.reshape(-1, 1)
```

where the `-1` automatically finds the value of `n`.

Comment: But if it is neither row and column what is the result of a matrix multiplication? For example ```A``` is 2x2 and ```b``` is array of length 2. Then ```A @ b``` is what ? So we see with that example that b HAS to be a column vector!

Comment: @LorisFoe: `b @ A` also gives something. by that example, we see that it can't be a column vector. look up *broadcasting*

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use ndmin option of numpy.array. Keeping it to 2 says that it will be a (4,1) and transpose will be (1,4).

```
>>> a = np.array([12, 3, 4, 5], ndmin=2)
>>> print a.shape
>>> (1,4)
>>> print a.T.shape
>>> (4,1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can store the array's elements in a row or column as follows:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])[:, None] # stores in rows
>>> a
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

>>> b = np.array([1, 2, 3])[None, :] # stores in columns
>>> b
array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a distiction for this case I would recommend to use a `matrix` instead, where:

```
matrix([1,2,3]) == matrix([1,2,3]).transpose()
```

gives:

```
matrix([[ True, False, False],
        [False,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

You can also use a `ndarray` explicitly adding a second dimension:

```
array([1,2,3])[None,:]
#array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

and:

```
array([1,2,3])[:,None]
#array([[1],
#       [2],
#       [3]])
```

Comment: `array([1,2,3])[None,:]` is much more complicated than the explicit `array([[1, 2, 3]])`.

Comment: `matrix` is generally worth avoiding, as it doesn't generalize to higher dimensions

Answer (score 3):

If I want a 1x3 array, or 3x1 array:

```
import numpy as np
row_arr = np.array([1,2,3]).reshape((1,3))
col_arr = np.array([1,2,3]).reshape((3,1)))
```

Check your work:

```
row_arr.shape  #returns (1,3)
col_arr.shape  #returns (3,1)
```

I found a lot of answers here are helpful, but much too complicated for me. In practice I come back to `shape` and `reshape` and the code is readable: very simple and explicit.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Python's Numpy doesn't distinguish it unless you use it in context:

"You can have standard vectors or row/column vectors if you like. "

"    :) You can treat rank-1 arrays as either row or column vectors. dot(A,v) treats v as a column vector, while dot(v,A) treats v as a row vector. This can save you having to type a lot of transposes. "

Also, specific to your code: "Transpose on a rank-1 array does nothing. "
Source:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)

Comment: I know that. I want a way to differentiate them. Maybe some other math module?

Answer (score 2):

When I tried to compute `w^T * x` using numpy, it was super confusing for me as well. In fact, I couldn't implement it myself. So, this is one of the few gotchas in NumPy that we need to acquaint ourselves with.

As far as *1D array* is concerned, there is **no distinction between a row vector and column vector**. They are exactly the same.

Look at the following examples, where we get the same result in all cases, which is not true in (*the theoretical sense of*) linear algebra:

```
In [37]: w
Out[37]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [38]: x
Out[38]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [39]: np.dot(w, x)
Out[39]: 40

In [40]: np.dot(w.transpose(), x)
Out[40]: 40

In [41]: np.dot(w.transpose(), x.transpose())
Out[41]: 40

In [42]: np.dot(w, x.transpose())
Out[42]: 40
```

---

With that information, now let's try to compute the squared length of the vector `|w|^2`.

For this, we need to transform `w` to 2D array.

```
In [51]: wt = w[:, np.newaxis]

In [52]: wt
Out[52]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Now, let's compute the squared length (or squared magnitude) of the vector `w` :

```
In [53]: np.dot(w, wt)
Out[53]: array([30])
```

Note that we used `w`, `wt` instead of `wt`, `w` (like in theoretical linear algebra) because of shape mismatch with the use of np.dot(wt, w). So, we have the squared length of the vector as `[30]`. Maybe this is one of the ways to distinguish (numpy's interpretation of) row and column vector?

And finally, did I mention that I figured out the way to implement `w^T * x` ? Yes, I did :

```
In [58]: wt
Out[58]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])

In [59]: x
Out[59]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [60]: np.dot(x, wt)
Out[60]: array([40])
```

So, in NumPy, the order of the operands is reversed, as evidenced above, contrary to what we studied in theoretical linear algebra.

---

**P.S.** : [potential gotchas in numpy](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/03/12/Potential-gotchas-in-linear-algebra-in-numpy/)

Comment: if you try doing `np.hstack` or `np.vstack` on a list of 1-D arrays, it does actually make a difference! If each of the arrays has shape `(10, )`, the results for `hstack` is `(20,)` and for `vstack` it is `(2, 10)`. This means they are assumed to be column vectors!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another intuitive way. Suppose we have:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 3, 4])
>>> a
array([1, 3, 4])
```

First we make a 2D array with that as the only row:

```
>>> a = np.array([a])
>>> a
array([[1, 3, 4]])
```

Then we can transpose it:

```
>>> a.T
array([[1],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

row vectors are (1,0) tensor, vectors are (0, 1) tensor. if using v = np.array([[1,2,3]]), v become (0,2) tensor. Sorry, i am confused.

Answer (score -1):

The excellent [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library adds features to numpy that make these kinds of operations more intuitive IMO. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# column
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])

# row
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]])
```

You can even [define a DataFrame and make a spreadsheet-like pivot table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-pivot).

Comment: Since you can write the same thing in NumPy, I would add the important fact that both `df[0] = 10` and `df2[0] = 10` work as expected when thinking of row and column vectors. This is where Pandas is convenient, compared to NumPy.