# Concatenate np.arrays python

Tags: python, numpy

How can I do if:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[5,6,7]])

b = np.array([0,1])
```

I search to concatenate `a` and `b` so as the result would be:

```
np.array([1,2,3,0],[5,6,7,1])
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more numpythonic way to do this is to avoid broadcasting, and use the function designed for this: [`numpy.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
np.column_stack([a, b])
```

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [5, 6, 7, 1]])
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that! And it's implemented essentially as @Wen's answer. Fun! :)

Comment: Yep, `column_stack` is the only one of the stacking functions (I believe), that converts 1D inputs to 2D columns, so works perfectly here.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is to concatenate `a` horizontally with `b` as a column vector.

```
<concat>( |1 2 3|, |0| )
          |5 6 7|  |1|
```

The concatentation can be done using [np.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), and `b` can be [converted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428621/python-differentiating-between-row-and-column-vectors) into a column vector by adding a new axis:

```
>>> np.hstack([a, b[:, np.newaxis]])
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [5, 6, 7, 1]])
```

Comment: @Yuca: There is no distinction between a row and a column vector for a 1d array. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42908123/463796 for more on that.

Comment: @Yuca you can use the transpose with `np.atleast_2d`: `np.hstack([a, np.atleast_2d(b).T])`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy` broadcast with `concatenate`

```
np.concatenate([a,b[:,None]],1)
Out[1053]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [5, 6, 7, 1]])
```