# Is a new transposed vector in NumPy a column or row vector by default?

Tags: numpy, transpose

I'm a new learner in the Python language. When a new vector is generated, is it a column or row vector by default?

```
import numpy as np

theta = np.arange(3)
a = len(theta.T)
b = len(theta)
print('theta = {} \n theta.T = {}'.format(theta,theta.T))
c = theta.T.dot(theta)
d = theta.dot(theta.T)
```

It turns out `a == b == 3`, `c == d`, and both `theta` and `theta.T` are displayed as a row vector.

But this matters when I want to calculate the derivative of of symbolic function *x* · *x*<sup>*T*</sup> with *x* a row vector.

Comment: By default, numpy will treat both vector and transpose vector as the same, so when you find the dot product of `x@x`, you can still get the answer.

Comment: It's neither a row nor a column vector since it is not a 2D array. `np.array` are not vectors or matrices.

Comment: `np.transpose` explains what happens to a 1-D array.  `np.dot` explains how it handles 1-D arrays.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Differentiating between row and column vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428621/python-differentiating-between-row-and-column-vectors)

Answer (score 1):

Neither, it is a 1D array as:

```
>>> theta.shape
(3,)
```

A column vector would have a shape equal to `(3,1)`, a row vector: `(1,3)`. You can create it by changing the shape

```
>>> theta.shape = (1,3)
>>> theta
array([[0, 1, 2]])
>>> theta.shape = (3,1)
>>> theta
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

Comment: Thanks，your explanation is quite clear and understandable